# Template Nested Class with Inheritance File Separation

Tags: c++, file, templates, inheritance, nested

I writed a program in only one file.
But Now, I want to separate to header and cpp files.
But in my program there are templated class,inheritance,and nested class.So I am confusing.

I have 4 class which : BaseAbstract, Derived1, Nested, Derived2.

I think there is 4*2+1=9 file but I am not sure.

You can see my code.(I simplified it to facilitate for your answers)

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;



    template <class T>
    class BaseAbstract{
    public:
        class NestedClass;
        virtual int count (const T& val)=0;
    };


    template <class T>
    class Derived1:public BaseAbstract<T>{

    protected:
        shared_ptr<T>dataS;
        int sizeS;
        int capacity;

    public:

        Derived1(){
            sizeS=0;
            capacity=0;
        }

        class NestedClass{
        protected:
            T* data;
        public:
            NestedClass(){
                data=new T;
            }
            T* getData(){
                return data;
            }
            NestedClass& operator++(){
                data++;
                return *this;
            }

        };

        int count (const T& val){
            for(int i=0;i<sizeS;i++){
                if(dataS.get()[i]==val){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }

    };


    template <class K,class V>
    class Derived2:public Derived1<pair<K, V> >{
    public:
        Derived2():Derived1<pair<K, V> >(){

            this->capacity=10000;

            this->dataS=dataS1;
        }


    };

    int main(void){

        Derived1<int> a;

    }
```

Comment: Usually you need only 2 files header and implementation. You would only need 2 or 3 if you include main

Comment: @JakeFreeman But I want to create .cpp and header for all classes.

Comment: In that case you need 6 files because your nested class would usually be in the class in which it is nested. 7 if you include main. Also 4*2 + 1 = 9 not 10

Comment: @JakeFreeman Yes It must be 9 . I write wrong. Can you separate? For this code.

Comment: Ok I will do that now

Comment: Posted the separated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your code into these files. The class `BaseAbstract` goes into `BaseAbstract.h`. The implementation of class `Derived1` including the `Nested` class into `Dervived1.cpp` and the definitions in `Derived1.h`. The class `Derived2` definition should be in `Derived2.h` and the implementation in `Derived2.cpp`. I will post the separated code later.

In the file `BaseAbstract.h` standard C++ includes and namespaces.

```
template <class T>
class BaseAbstract{
public:
    class NestedClass;
    virtual int count (const T& val)=0;
};
```

In the file `Derived1.h` includes BaseAbstract.h

```
template <class T>
class Derived1:public BaseAbstract<T>{

protected:
    shared_ptr<T>dataS;
    int sizeS;
    int capacity;

public:

    Derived1();

    class NestedClass;

    int count (const T& val);

};
```

In the file `Derived1.cpp` includes Derived1.h

```
Derived1::Derived1()
{
    sizeS = 0;
    capacity = 0;
}
```

In the file Nested.h includes Derived1.h

```
    Derived1::NestedClass
    {
    protected:
        T* data;
    public:
        NestedClass();

        T* getData();
        NestedClass& operator++();

    };
```

In the file Nested.cpp includes Nested.h

```
template<class T>
Derived1::NestedClass::NestedClass() { data = new T; }

template<class T>
T* Derived1::NestedClass::getData() { return data; }

template<class T>
NestedClass& Derived1::NestedClass::operator++()
{
    data++;
    return data;
}
```

In the file `Derived2.h` includes Derived1.h

```
template <class K,class V>
class Derived2:public Derived1<pair<K, V> >{
public:
    Derived2():Derived1<pair<K, V> >();


};
```

In the file `Derived2.cpp` includes Derived2.h

```
    Derived2():Derived1<pair<K, V> >()
    {

        this->capacity=10000;

        this->dataS=dataS1;
    }
```

In the file `main.cpp` includes Derived2.h

```
int main(void){

    Derived1<int> a;

}
```

Comment: Which files must be include at top ?

Comment: @EasterGamer ok I added that

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think in main.cpp have to include .cpp files because of tamplates.Why don't you do that?

Comment: Because it is in the definition file. If this answered your question please upvote and accept

Comment: Could you write NestedClass to another files (NestedClass.cpp and NestedClass.h)?If you have time?

Comment: Sure @EasterGamer it will be in a few minutes though

Comment: @EasterGamer I added the NestedClass files. If this helps don't forget to upvote.